# How to create/define Adob Omniture (adob analytics) ADBMobileConfig.json file for android

Tags: android, adobe-analytics

I am trying to integrate Adob Omniture analytics (Adobe Marketing Cloud) in my android application. I just want to know that, how I can configure ADBMobileConfig.json file, any guidance link. How to define value of this in json file

```
{
Analytics: rsids and server,
Target: clientCode,
Audience Management: server
}
```

Right now my json file is like this

```
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "analytics" : {
        "rsids" : "",
        "server" : "",
        "charset" : "UTF-8",
        "ssl" : false,
        "offlineEnabled" : false,
        "lifecycleTimeout" : 300,
        "batchLimit" : 0,
        "privacyDefault" : "optedin",
        "poi" : []
    },
    "target" : {
        "clientCode" : "",
        "timeout" : 2
    },
    "audienceManager" : {
        "server" : ""
    }
}
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config reference:
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/mobile/android/#Adobe_Mobile_Class_and_Method_Reference

developer.omniture.com has just about everything you'd need to get going.

Comment: But how they create ADBMobileConfig.json. How they define rsid,target etc, where it is created.

Comment: @AmolWadekar If you scroll down in that link I posted, you'll see the ADBMObileConfig.json File Reference section. File goes in the assets folder, rsids are created by your Analytics Admin and are report suite ids. Target is something provide by your Target admin, if you're not using it, leave it out.

Comment: Thanks BrettAHale for your reply, but I want to follow the process of Analytics Admin (as you mention), so my question is where I am look so that I get more information about Analytics Admin, so that I get rsid & other info.

Comment: You either have to have admin access to the company's account or you have to have access to the admin of the company. In the admin section, you'll find a report suite section. That will have a list of all rsid and report suite names and settings.

Answer (score 2):

The link in BrettAHale's answer is unfortunately dead. After spending way too much time hunting through Adobe Marketing's ill-conceived site, Google finally found a PDF documenting the config file:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/android/android_mobile_4x.pdf

Locating the values to plug in from the Adobe Analytics (Omniture) account is another challenge all unto itself. Anyone with experience wading through that morass please do share.

Based on Adobe's past behavior, that link will likely die a horrible death as well. Might want to save that and keep it somewhere safe.

PS: For posterity http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00262289428317514323